Pyspark Azure Synapse - kryoserializer Buffer overflow
I am facing a problem with the Azure Synapse Notebook. I have a big python script where is used the Pandas Dataframe, I can load a 'parquet' file, but I cannot convert into pandas using toPandas(), because is throwing the error: 'org.apache.spark.SparkException: Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow'.
It is not a huge data, it is just 7 millions rows and 80 columns.
I have tried:

Added more resources to the cluster and is not working.

Trying to modify the buffer size


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("YourAppName") \
    .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") \
    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "512m") \  
    .getOrCreate()

But it is not working either.

Reduce number of columns and it is not working.

The only thing that worked was reduce rows, but that is not an option, I need whole records.
I need to keep the same code as well (no changing into pyspark)
I hope someone could have an idea of how to fix it.
Thanks

Just solved my own problem. Looks that the configuration cannot be setup in the the notebook directly, but in the configure session.
So basically must: Manage -> Apache Spark Configuration -> New.
After this, must be added in the Spark pool used: Manage -> Spark Pool -> click on three dots -> Apache spark configuration -> add it.
Finally must publish it
Configuration
